# How to use Shopify Node API to retrieve an access token from a session with Amazon AWS API Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, shopify, aws-api-gateway, shopify-app

I have a custom function that validates the Shopify session token and returns the decoded JWT

```
        {
          iss: The shop's admin domain.
          dest: The shop's domain.
          aud: The API key of the receiving app.
          sub: The user that the session token is intended for.
          exp: When the session token expires.
          nbf: When the session token activates.
          iat: When the session token was issued.
          jti: A secure random UUID.
          sid: A unique session ID per user and app.
        }
```

Then, I initialize the context with Shopify.Context.initialize({...})

How can I get the access token using:

```
const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(req, res)
```

Right now, I'm saving the access token in a database during the initial install since I don't know how to use the function above with AWS API Gateway.

What should be req and res knowing that a Lambda handler has event and context as parameters?
I feel req = event. But I have no idea what res should be in this case.

Comment: You should add the lambda language to the tags

Comment: There is no "lambda language". The post has already been tagged with aws-lambda. Adding Nodejs

Comment: Lambda supports a number of language runtime such as go, javascript,  python,  Java,  etc